# python dictionary update custom

Tags: python, dictionary, callback, nested

Is there a way to pass a callback function or use a custom logic whether to update some value, when having a nested dictionary ?

Scenario:
Given dict b and dict a.
I need to have the structure from dict a, inside dict b
When update, to replace the value if certain condition is met.

Comment: Subclass `dict` and add your custom logic.

Comment: Dont subclass `dict` - write a real class implementing the desired interface AND behaviour.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what exactly does **real class** mean? Additionally the desired interface is similar to that of the `dict` object you only need to change the behavior on `update`. Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry I meant a "domain model" class. And we don't know whether the __desired__ interface is really dict-like - we only know the OP __uses__ nested dicts, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: Thing is the dict b is the main data in the program,  "dict a" has default stuff, what I need is to update "dict b" when something is empty or something is X case.

Comment: This is what end up making: https://gist.github.com/gnud/426bc5109c45d7892b7d, it's not OO, but it did the job, if anyone have alternative made using the override of update method, will be lovely :).